# "Cannot find or open the PDB file." for Qt6 commercial release debug symbol files

Tags: visual-c++, qt6

I'm trying to debug my project.  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and Qt 4.6.2 Commercial.  I'd like to step into Qt library code, but cannot because

> Cannot find or open the PDB file.

I've double checked what I've downloaded from Qt matches (their MD5 file agree with what I downloaded).

I inspected the dll and pdb signatures for the debug Qt Core DLL:

`dumpbin.exe Qt6Cored.dll` has the lines:

> ```
> Debug Directories
>
>     Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
> -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
> 6397073D cv            44 00C6B300   C69B00    Format: RSDS, {B713CCD9-B63E-45B8-BAB2-1165E50F2E75}, 1,
> C:\Users\qt\work\qt\qtbase\bin\Qt6Cored.pdb
> 6397073D feat          14 00C6B344   C69B44    Counts: Pre-VC++ 11.00=0, C/C++=305, /GS=305, /sdl=0, guardN=50
> ```

`dbh.exe Qt6Cored.pdb info` gives the line:

```
PdbSig70 : 0xb8de71e0, 0xe814, 0x4e1c, 0xbc, 0x37, 0xb8, 0xc1, 0x4a, 0xe8, 0x94, 0xde
```

After formatting both IDs, you see the mismatch:

```
B713CCD9B63E45B8BAB21165E50F2E75 (dll)
B8DE71E0E8144E1CBC37B8C14AE894DE (pdb)
```

We have contacted Qt and they said "This seems working here with 2019".

Is anyone else seeing this issue?  Or did I do something wrong with my analysis?  Also, if someone has a workaround/hack (other than rebuilding Qt ourselves), let me know.

I created [QTBUG-112989](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-112989) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Qt got back to us - and it is a problem with the offline installers/PDB files available for download.  **Using the online installers** for Qt 6.4.3, the DLLs and PDB files match.  Example:

```
Qt6Core.dll EA4BB91BFEB8405EB812141B301B1B191
Qt6Core.pdb EA4BB91BFEB8405EB812141B301B1B191
```